# page explodes memory usage to 80MB and then dies

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm using asp.net and chrome and the page becomes unresponsive after a while. When I look at the chrome debug, I see that memory usage increases to about 80MB and chrome popups a request to kill the page. The error counter spins and generates about 30,000 errors when the popup comes. What triggers the error is the call of an updatepanel. The error as displayed in chrome is "Failed to load resource".

The update panel: the user clicks on a button and the panel is refreshed. There's only one update panel on the page.

This is what I have:

```
function HistoryUIActions() {
     $('.SelectDay, .SelectDay1Digit').click(function () { GetNewDate(this); });
};


function GetNewDate(thedateitem) {

    var TheDay = $.trim($(thedateitem).html());
    TheYear = 2011;
    ThisMonth = 2;

    DateString = ThisMonth + '/' + TheDay + '/' + TheYear;

    __doPostBack('<%= TheUpdatePanel.ClientID %>', DateString);
 };


function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    HistoryUIActions();
 };
```

The errors compound on every postback: 1,4, 11, 26, 57, 120, 247.... eventually chrome kills the page. When I put a breakpoint in the function, it stops the code just after I press the button; then after it hits the __doPostBack line, it starts the GetNewDate function again several times by going back to the line of the click event, apparently executing it the number of times shown above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the errors generated? It sounds like there is some kind of infinite loop going on somewhere but this code doesn't suggest anything to me. Is it making the postback? Is it making more than one? Is it just when you click on it that it becomes unresponsive (I'm assuming that is why you posted the above code?)...

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use .UniqueID in __doPostBack? I think this code will cause ALL UpdatePanels to be refreshed. Is there possibly another one that could be causing a chain reaction somehow?

Comment: What does EvalMonthYear() do?

Comment: @Paddy: there's a drop down that contains the month and the year (ie. February 2011) and the buttons that are the days (they're the ones the user clicks on and that trigger the GetNewDate function). EvalMonthYear reads the value of the drop down and assigns global variables TheMonth and TheYear with the numerical values of the corresponding month/year that are in the drop-down. The value TheDay is determined by the text of the button. The DateString variable assembles these 3 numbers to compose the date that's passed as the parameter.

Comment: You've clearly got some kind of fork going on here since the errors go double+n+1 (eg 1->1*2+1+1 = 4, 4->4*2+2+1 = 11, 11-> 11*2+3+1 = 26...). I don't think we have enough code here to work out what is going on though. What is getting loaded in? Could there be some script being fired off whenever the panel refreshes? And more importantly what are the errors that are being thrown up?

Comment: @chris: I've added the code of the request handler that I call after the postback. Everything else is commented out. The error I see in the chrome debugger is "Failed to load resource".

Comment: @Frenchie, where is the control that is being clicked on, and what is its type and properties? Is it possible that the control itself is a postback handler (the default, if it's inside the UpdatePanel), which would cause it to be refreshed once by ASP.NET and again by your jQuery-added click handler? My head's not quite around the consequences of that but I could see some badness like this happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh. :) After looking at this a dozen times, I think I have the answer, or at least part of it.

Your click control is outside the updatepanel. Yet you call "HistoryUIActions" to bind the click event with jQuery after each refresh. This will double the number of click events bound to your control every time you click it.

Click handlers are cumulative. You don't need to rebind it, unless the actual DOM element of the control has been re-rendered. Each time you click you are adding a duplicate handler.

This ought to solve the multiple-refresh problem, then you can figure out what's not loading properly after a click.

Comment: Thanks! you're right; you only rebind events that are in an updatepanel. Good to know!